# How can I make my icon image smaller in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, icons, flutter-layout

I'm planning to use my custom icon instead of using material icon but some reason I cannot make the image smaller. Any idea of suggestion on how I can make the image to smaller like the material icon on the right side.

I'm applied the width and height but some reason they can't get smaller than this. (attached image)

```
  Widget textField() {
    return TextField(
      enabled: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18, color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor),
          hintText: 'Search',
          prefixIcon: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 10,
              height: 10,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/icons/nav-icons/Explore.png',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          suffixIcon:
              Icon(Icons.mic, color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image widget has width and height property

```
Image.asset(
    "your/asset/path",
    width: PREFERRED_WIDTH,
    height: PREFERRED_HEIGHT,
),
```

Maybe you can add the prefixIconConstraints like this

```
 prefixIconConstraints: BoxConstraints(
     maxWidth: 20.0,
     maxHeight: 20.0,
 ),
```

Comment: Thanks...I already did that but it can't go smaller than the original size so I'm wondering how I can make it smaller than the original size.

Comment: So you can wrap your Image widget in SizedBox by specifying the width and the height of the SizedBox

Comment: Hi @dm_tr I tried with SizedBox but still doing nothing. Can you please look at my updated code above. thanks –

Comment: Oh ok, it fixed. thankyou. by anychance can you also please take alook at my other question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65397494/how-can-i-disabled-flutter-switch