# How can I disabled flutter switch

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In my help screen, I have this switch and the purpose for that is to do nothing but just display like the way it is.

But the problem I'm having right now, even though it doesn't do anything, the user can drag the switch so I'm trying to figure out how I can disabled it so that no one can drag the switch button.

```
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30, top: 10),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Dark Theme",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
              Switch(
                  value: true,
                  onChanged: (value) {},
                  activeColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
              Text("Light Theme", style: TextStyle())
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To disable your `Switch`, edit its `onChanged` method to null like this

```
Switch(
  onChanged: null,
  value: true,
  inactiveThumbColor: Colors.tealAccent,
  inactiveTrackColor: Colors.tealAccent.withOpacity(0.5),
  // ...
),
```

Comment: ohh..thanks it got disabled but it turn out not the way I imagined. The switch got disabled but the color doesn't applied to the switch anymore, do you know how can I applied light blue color(just like in the image) and make the switch still disabled?.

Comment: You can also use `Theme.of(context).accentColor` and `Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.5)` for example

Comment: oh ok...but I think I'm not allow to use both inactiveThumbColor and inactiveTrackColor at the same time because I'm getting error. (attached image) do you know what might be the reason. thanks

Comment: it saying Undefined name 'inactiveTrackColor'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: Close your widget with `)` symbol

Comment: It work!.. Thank you so much for your help on both of my question. thanks you

Comment: Sorry dm_tr hehe.. I got one more question and can you help me out again too... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65398159/how-to-disabled-switch-tab-in-flutter .. thank you so much if you can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226253/discussion-between-dm-tr-and-aase-zi).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to have static switch with manually set value, consider using AbsorbPointer. It will not change way your switch looks and will not disable it.
AbsorbPointer is just preventing user from interacting with element

Comment: This should be the answer, thanks for teaching me about a new widget.

Comment: Didn't know about the existence of this widget, really useful. +1