# How to disabled switch tab in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

In my help page, I have this switch tab but I'm wondering how can I disabled it so that when a user click on the word "Trending", it will not do anything.

I just want to display the way it's right now no matter where the user click but right now the tab got switch when ever a user click on the the word "trending".

Any help or suggestion on how I can disabled it will be really appreciated.

```
 Widget tabBarWidget() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1)),
      child: TabBar(
        controller: TabController(length: 2, vsync: this),
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            text: 'Recommended',
          ),
          Tab(
            text: 'Trending',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this adding empty function call or null onTap like this

```
Widget tabBarWidget() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1)),
      child: TabBar(
        controller: TabController(length: 2, vsync: this),
        onTap:(i){}, // or onTap: null,
        tabs: [
          Tab(
            text: 'Recommended',
          ),
          Tab(
            text: 'Trending',
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this but still not working and it's still switching the tab. any more suggestion?. :(